# Vector que devuelva índice de columnas de data frame según nombre de ellas

Tags: r, rstudio, vectores, multi-index

Para la pregunta formulada, en Rstudio, dada una data frame cualquiera, actualmente encontré la siguiente solución:

```
c(which(colnames(data) == "x"), which(colnames(data) == "y"), which(colnames(data) == "z"))
```

Sin embargo, me parece una solución un poco reiterativa, quisiera alguna forma más simple de lograrlo y con menos código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`%in%`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/match) que te permite comparar vectores:

```
which(colnames(data) %in% c("x", "y", "z"))
```

Comment: Gracias! Hay algun atajo para ingresar %in% ?

Comment: En Rstudio? no, lamentablemente no, lo más cercano es programar un snippet de código: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets-in-the-RStudio-IDE